# Maven project in eclipse - in which folder to put source files?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have created simple `maven` project in eclipse skipping archetype info. Below is the screenshot of project structure.

[image]

There are 2 folders created for Java marked in red and blue. Now if I want to put Java source files where should I put them in `src/main/java` folder or `java` folder inside `main`. Similarly if I want to put files in `resources` which folder should I use `src/main/resources` or `resources` folder inside `main` folder.
One more question I have is if for example I use src/main/java folder for my java files then what is use of other java folder inside main folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They both are same. Only thing is your IDE is showing first one in Java build path format and other one as normal. If you go to folder structure you would notice that they are physically same path.

But still since your IDE is differentiating them, use the one in Red for Java Classes.